# How to update tkinter window every 4 seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, tkinter, seconds

I am trying to create a program that reads lines from a file and puts them into a tkinter window. At the moment my code is this:

```
def read_notifications():
    #def update():
    #   window.config(text=str(random.random()))
    #   window.after(1000, update)
    aaa = 1
    while True:
        re = open("Y:/System Info/notifications.txt", "r")
        rf = re.read()
        rh = rf.count("\n")
        re.close()
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("Y:/System Info/notifications.txt")]
        rk = -1
        while True:
            aaa = aaa + 2
            rk = rk + 1
            #print(lines[rk])
            rl = rk + 1
            ya = lines[rk].split("#")
            yb = str(tomrt)
            if ya[1] == yb:
                yc = "Tommorow"
            else:
                if ya[1] == "0":
                    yc = "Monday"
                if ya[1] == "1":
                    yc = "Tuesday"
                if ya[1] == "2":
                    yc = "Wednesday"
                if ya[1] == "3":
                    yc = "Thursday"
                if ya[1] == "4":
                    yc = "Friday"
                if ya[1] == "5":
                    yc = "Saturday"
                if ya[1] == "6":
                    yc = "Sunday"       
            c = 650
            window = tk.Tk()
            #back = tk.Frame(width=700, height=c)
            #back.pack()
            window.title("Notifications")
            window.iconbitmap("1235.ico")
            #Subject
            lbl = tk.Label(window, text=ya[0])
            lbl.config(font=("Courier", 18))
            lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
            #lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT,)
            #Day
            lbl = tk.Label(window, text=" " + yc)
            lbl.config(font=("Courier", 16))
            lbl.grid(column=2, row=0)
            #Type
            lbl = tk.Label(window, text=ya[2])
            lbl.config(font=("Courier", 16))
            lbl.grid(column=4, row=0)
            #Descripion
            lbl = tk.Label(window, text=ya[4])
            lbl.config(font=("Courier", 16))
            lbl.grid(column=6, row=0)
            #lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            #window.after(1000, update)
            if rl == rh:
                print("hello")
                break
        if aaa > 2:
            time.sleep(4)
            window.destroy()
        else:
            window.mainloop()
```

I am not sure why this doesn't work properly. I am trying to make it so the tkinter window will update itself every 4 seconds, as another program is making changes to the notifications.txt file and I want the tkinter windows to update accordingly.

Comment: Why is all of your program inside of a function? There are several issues here. One that stands out right away is the use of  `sleep()`. The sleep method will freeze tkinter and you do not need to worry about tkinter updating as the mainloop is a constant loop that updates the event loop all on its own.

Comment: @Mike-SMT It is part of a larger program, so this function gets called when somebody types something in.

Comment: I still find it odd that you have a tkinter instance inside of a function. Is your main program already a tkinter instance? If so then you should use `Toplevel()` in this function instead.

Comment: @Mike-SMT No,my main program is just a program that lets you type a command and it will do it (f it knows what the command means).

Comment: @Ethan Gascoigne. What does notifications.txt look like?

Answer (score 1):

You code is a bit hard to re-work but here is a working example of how one can monitor a file.

Say I have a file that contains 4 lines and we call this file `my_file`:

```
1 test
2 testing
3 more testing
4 test again
```

All we want to do is update the labels ever 4 seconds so we can use the `after()` method to keep us going.

Take a look at this below code.

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Notifications")
file_to_monitor = "./my_file.txt"

def read_notifications():
    with open(file_to_monitor, "r") as f:
        x = f.read()
        string_list = x.split("\n")

    lbl1.config(text=string_list[0])
    lbl2.config(text=string_list[1])
    lbl3.config(text=string_list[2])
    lbl4.config(text=string_list[3])

    window.after(4000, read_notifications)


lbl1 = tk.Label(window, text="")
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0, stick="w")
lbl2 = tk.Label(window, text="")
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=1, stick="w")
lbl3 = tk.Label(window, text="")
lbl3.grid(column=0, row=2, stick="w")
lbl4 = tk.Label(window, text="")
lbl4.grid(column=0, row=3, stick="w")

read_notifications()
window.mainloop()
```

What we start out with on the first read:

[image]

Then after I have made a change to the file and saved from my notepad:

[image]

Comment: plus one for the testing bit

Comment: @ReblochonMasque :D ty.

Comment: Shame on you for numbering variable names. Those Labels should be in a list.

Comment: @Novel lol. I know but I thought the visual would be good for the OP as it seams they are new to tkinter.

Comment: @Mike-SMT  This isn't working for me, as the variable need to be defined before the section that follows c = 650, otherwise it gives an error. Is there a way to run read_notifications once before that?

Comment: It depends on how you write the code @EthanGascoigne. If you write the functions inside of the Tkinter instance it should not need the variable name from the global written first. Your example may need to include some more code so we can properly test your problem. Please take a look at this post and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Mike-SMT I added read_notifications() just before the c =650 bit, but it still didn't work, I don't know why?

Comment: @EthanGascoigne I will take a look at the pastebin when I get home tonight. I cannot open it at work due to company firewall.